# Как поменять цвет объекта, созданного в скрипте, при нажатии на него в WinForms C#?

Tags: c#, winforms

У меня есть PictureBox, который я создаю в коде и добавляю в Controls, но как мне сделать так, чтобы при нажатии на этот PictureBox его цвет менялся к примеру на белый? При чём из-за того, что я создаю его в коде я не могу задать это в самом конструкторе и этих PictureBox будет очень много, по этому мне обязательно нужно создавать их из скрипта.

```
private void GenerateButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    PictureBox pb = new PictureBox()
    { 
        Size = new Size(20, 20), 
        Location = new Point(200, 100), 
        BackColor = Color.Black 
    };

    this.Controls.Add(pb);
}

//Выполнять метод при нажатии на объекту
public void ChangeColor(PictureBox pictureBox)
{
    if (pictureBox.BackColor == Color.Black)
        pictureBox.BackColor = Color.White
    else if (pictureBox.BackColor == Color.White)
        pictureBox.BackColor = Color.Black
}
```

Comment: Советую вам познать привязки, даже в старом WinForms они есть, и они будут делать за вас всю эту работу. Ну а так, на одно событие их подцепите, и вон к примеру `GenerateButton_Click`, у него есть `sender` - это тот объект, который вызвал событие, присваивайте его к нужному типу и меняйте что хотите (условно `if (sender is PictureBox pictureBox){ //Делаем что-то с pictureBox }`).

Comment: @EvgeniyZ не злоупотребляйте паттерн матчингом в методах, где жестко ожидается один конкретный тип, например в обработчике события для контрола определенного типа, где по правилам `sender` не может быть `null`, и имеет конкретный тип. Если же `sender` при использовании простого даункаста выдаст `InvalidCastException`, это будет проще обнаружить и поправить код, чем выяснять, а почему же код в обработчике не отрабатывает, ставить брейкпоинты и т.д. Например я по ошибке воткнул не тот обработчик в контрол и запустил приложение, такой баг будет моментально локализован.

Comment: @aepot Ну, яб это назвал придиркой на пустом месте (привет `var` и указание явного типа). Все зависит от конечной цели, да и стиля написания кода. Ну а по поводу кидать исключение или просто обработать это и пройти мимо - я за второе, код должен быть понятный и лаконичный, без лишних ошибок и так далее. Критичное место, всунуть туда запись в лог если условие `false` и готово. `sender не может быть null` - иногда бывает. `определенного типа` - обычно такие обработчики универсальны, и под несколько типов, мы же не будем кнопке одно писать, а картинке другое, дублируя тем самым код...

Comment: @EvgeniyZ это была не придирка, а совет. Вам решать, слушать его или нет. Я сам на этих матчингах один баг дебажил неделю, а оказалось что просто `is` не отрабатывал там, где 100% должен был. Поделился опытом, а вы "придиркой" это назвали, обидно. Как по мне, там где оно должно падать - оно должно падать. Чем раньше вылетит исключение, если что-то пошло не так, тем лучше, сам .NET так устроен.